# Split text file into short lines for reading?

Tags: text-processing

Is there a program that can take a plain-text file with long lines, and add a newline after a certain number of characters, only splitting at words, to make it readable? For example, take this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vel lectus ac enim venenatis porttitor in et est. Curabitur ut eros quis risus consequat dictum a a lectus. Integer ut risus quis augue lobortis molestie vel id nibh. Aliquam sit amet mattis lorem, vel ornare felis. Donec pulvinar tempus lorem, at porta sem pretium ut. Cras ut lorem tincidunt, scelerisque nunc vitae, posuere augue. Vestibulum iaculis libero id congue ultrices. Nullam mauris ipsum, aliquet eget nisl non, venenatis euismod enim. Phasellus a eleifend velit. Aenean molestie venenatis turpis, consectetur convallis velit fringilla non.
```

And turn it into this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vel
lectus ac enim venenatis porttitor in et est. Curabitur ut eros quis
risus consequat dictum a a lectus. Integer ut risus quis augue lobortis
molestie vel id nibh. Aliquam sit amet mattis lorem, vel ornare felis.
Donec pulvinar tempus lorem, at porta sem pretium ut. Cras ut lorem
tincidunt, scelerisque nunc vitae, posuere augue. Vestibulum iaculis
libero id congue ultrices. Nullam mauris ipsum, aliquet eget nisl non,
venenatis euismod enim. Phasellus a eleifend velit. Aenean molestie
venenatis turpis, consectetur convallis velit fringilla non.
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The command I think you're looking for is called `fmt`.

```
$ fmt loremipsum.txt
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vel
lectus ac enim venenatis porttitor in et est. Curabitur ut eros quis risus
consequat dictum a a lectus. Integer ut risus quis augue lobortis molestie
vel id nibh. Aliquam sit amet mattis lorem, vel ornare felis. Donec
pulvinar tempus lorem, at porta sem pretium ut. Cras ut lorem tincidunt,
scelerisque nunc vitae, posuere augue. Vestibulum iaculis libero id congue
ultrices. Nullam mauris ipsum, aliquet eget nisl non, venenatis euismod
enim. Phasellus a eleifend velit. Aenean molestie venenatis turpis,
consectetur convallis velit fringilla non.
```

You can control the results, such as width, etc.

```
$ fmt --help
Usage: fmt [-WIDTH] [OPTION]... [FILE]...
Reformat each paragraph in the FILE(s), writing to standard output.
The option -WIDTH is an abbreviated form of --width=DIGITS.

Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
  -c, --crown-margin        preserve indentation of first two lines
  -p, --prefix=STRING       reformat only lines beginning with STRING,
                              reattaching the prefix to reformatted lines
  -s, --split-only          split long lines, but do not refill
  -t, --tagged-paragraph    indentation of first line different from second
  -u, --uniform-spacing     one space between words, two after sentences
  -w, --width=WIDTH         maximum line width (default of 75 columns)
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit

With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.
```

Answer (score 5):

Probably the best choice would be a text editor; most of them offer text wrapping of some kind.

If you're looking for something more plain, you could come up with something using `sed` or similar. Putting your long line into a `loremipsum.txt`, and letting `sed` wrap after 56-73 characters followed by space, it gives your desired result...

```
$ sed -r -e 's/.{56,73} /&\n/g' loremipsum.txt
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vel 
lectus ac enim venenatis porttitor in et est. Curabitur ut eros quis 
risus consequat dictum a a lectus. Integer ut risus quis augue lobortis 
molestie vel id nibh. Aliquam sit amet mattis lorem, vel ornare felis. 
Donec pulvinar tempus lorem, at porta sem pretium ut. Cras ut lorem 
tincidunt, scelerisque nunc vitae, posuere augue. Vestibulum iaculis 
libero id congue ultrices. Nullam mauris ipsum, aliquet eget nisl non, 
venenatis euismod enim. Phasellus a eleifend velit. Aenean molestie 
venenatis turpis, consectetur convallis velit fringilla non.
```

...or you could just use `fold -s -w 74 loremipsum.txt` I guess...

Answer (score 3):

You can pipe your text in `fold -s -w 72` to get that result.

If your system does not have `fold` but has python installed you can do:

```
cat /var/tmp/li.txt | cat /var/tmp/li.txt | python -c "import sys; from textwrap import fill; print fill(sys.stdin.read(), width=72)"
```